# What tool to build a clients database and agenda?

Tags: windows, linux, database, cross-platform

Background:

> A friend of mine wants to upgrade his
>   computer. He is using an old
>   proprietary tool to manage his clients
>   files and agenda. This tool won't work
>   on a modern OS, he could emulate or
>   virtualise it, but he was never fully
>   satisfied with it. He did not find any
>   software one the market that fits his
>   needs, having some time for a side
>   project he would like to develop his
>   own database. He does not have any
>   programming skills (yet). The data
>   filled in the proprietary software is
>   easily exported as XML files. He would
>   like this new tool to be platform
>   independent.

So, what tool would be best to build a cross-platform client database software with a linked agenda ?

So far I advised him to have a look to [Opennoffice.org's Base module](http://www.openoffice.org/), because it fits his skill set.

As he does not need a server running, I would advise against a PHP/MySQL solution, mainly for security reasons (I know it's easy to secure, but he would have to also learn about security).

I would personally get this project done with python and sqlite (adding to the mix wxpython for the looks and sqlalchemy for my SQL allergy), but I fear that he doesn't have enough time for this project to acquire some coding skills in the process.

As a side question, is there some nice resources introducing databases concepts to beginners?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the name of the tool..That will help to recommend a solution

Comment: @kishore: I would if i remembered its name, he only demoed it quickly to me, and i just checked that the data was easily extracted from it. I will ask him the next time I see him. It's a small french patient-management tool aimed at osteopaths, that's all i can tell you for now - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I'm clear on exactly what you mean by 'linked agenda', but this sounds weel within the capabilities of OpenOffice.  If it's in you're friends skill set, it's a good choice - especially if not willing to learn something new & time is short.

If you're friend could learn (or be willing to learn) Tcl, Python or Ruby, I think these are also good choices.  They all have excellent docs / examples available on the web, can produce UI quickly & easily (depending on how you feel about 'easy') and have libraries available to make database access relatively painless.  Although unless you're willing to provide some encouragement, this is not a project I would throw at someone who has never programmed before.

However they choose to proceed, you'll likely be writing some SQL eventually.  Regarding some decent simple tutorials & resources:

1. [This](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/introduction.html) is an easy to read introduction on database concepts, if you like a conversational style.
2. [Geekgirls](http://www.geekgirls.com/menu_databases.htm) has a nice generic database tutorial that is pretty application / technology neutral.
3. W3 Schools has a good, not too deep [SQL Tutorial & Quiz](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

If your friend is serious about this topic, they should get a book that covers the tools and language they end up using.  As far as SQL, the O'Reilly [Learning SQL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596007272) and [Head First SQL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596526849) are good beginner books.  I like the informal visual style Head First uses, but YMMV.

Comment: @DaveParillo: Thanks for your answer. I was meaning by 'linked agenda' either an agenda inside the new tool either a capacity to export event to a calendar application. I was mainly posting this to know if I missed a tool like "database-made-supa-easy-for-beginners"(fictional), but your answer seems to confirm what I thought. Thanks for the links, that's what I was searching for. I too appreciate O'Reilly collection of computing book :)